# BeautifulSoup get_text() method on span returning quotes as part of string

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

Im using BeauitfulSoup `get_text()` method on the span tag by calling my parse_text function as

```
date = parse_text(soup.find('span'))
```

and then inserting the date next to some data in a dictionary to use with pandas as

```
data['date'] = [date] * number_rows
```

i then create a pandas dataframe from the dictionary and call .to_csv on the dataframe, but in the csv file all the dates show as "May 27, 2020" instead of just May 27, 2020

here is the parse_text function and html

```
   parse_text(element):
       return element.get_text().replace('\n', ' ').strip()
```

```html
<span>May 27, 2020</span>
```

Comment: Can u pls format the code, its very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

quickly after posting this I realize pandas .to_csv is inserting the quotes because of the present comma in the string, as it is the delimiter for the file... facepalm*